# Как удалить script src JS?

Tags: javascript

Как удалить код который внизу при помощи js.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/952238490/?random=1660291357378&amp;cv=9&amp;fst=1660291357378&amp;num=1&amp;bg=ffffff&amp;guid=ON&amp;resp=GooglemKTybQhCsO&amp;u_h=1440&amp;u_w=2560&amp;u_ah=1400&amp;u_aw=2560&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_his=5&amp;u_tz=180&amp;u_java=false&amp;u_nplug=5&amp;u_nmime=2&amp;gtm=2oa880&amp;sendb=1&amp;ig=1&amp;data=event%3Dform_submit&amp;frm=0&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fbooratino.com.ua%2Fcatalog%2Ffutbolka_s_vyshivkoj_fulikra&amp;ref=https%3A%2F%2Fbooratino.com.ua%2Fcatalog%2Ffutbolka_s_vyshivkoj_fulikra&amp;tiba=%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B7%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%2C%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0&amp;auid=1517977334.1653299278&amp;hn=www.googleadservices.com&amp;async=1&amp;rfmt=3&amp;fmt=4"></script>
```

Comment: Удалить откуда? Из строки с html-кодом, из DOM-дерева, откуда-то ещё? В браузере или в nodejs или в чём-то более экзотическом?

Comment: удалить тег можно с помощью метода [`remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)

Comment: Из DOM-дерева. Этот код автоматически добавляется. А мне нужно его просто убрать.

Comment: удаление тега, не спасет от выполнения кода